# railstutorial, This is deprecated behavior that will not be supported in RSpec 3

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm doing railstutorial, now chapter 11.

why this error?

> WARNING: let declaration `another_user` accessed in a `before(:all)`
>   hook at:
>   /Users/xxx/Documents/rails_projects/sample_app_2/spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:49:in
>   `block (4 levels) in '
>
> This is deprecated behavior that will not be supported in RSpec 3.
>
> `let` and `subject` declarations are not intended to be called in a
>   `before(:all)` hook, as they exist to define state that is reset
>   between each example, while `before(:all)` exists to define state that
>   is shared across examples in an example group. WARNING: let
>   declaration `another_user` accessed in a `before(:all)` hook at:
>   /Users/xxx/Documents/rails_projects/sample_app_2/spec/requests/micropost_pages_spec.rb:49:in
>   `block (4 levels) in '

my file is here. [enter link description here](https://github.com/jabropt/sample_app_2/tree/following-users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you have the following code:

```
let(:another_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
before(:all) do
  10.times { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: another_user, content: "Foooo") }
end
```

in which your `before(:all)` code makes use of the `another_user` variable, defined by `let`.

You can eliminate the warning by changing your `before(:all)` call to:

```
before(:all) do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  10.times { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foooo") }
end
```

Note that the tutorial as currently defined at railstutorial.org does not include any code which violates the restriction.

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, following code worked.

```
  describe "delete links" do
    before(:all) do
      @another_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      10.times { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: @another_user, content: "Foooo") }
    end

    after(:all)  do
      Micropost.delete_all
      User.delete_all
    end

    before { visit user_path(@another_user) }

    it "should not create delete link for not current user" do
      Micropost.paginate(page: 1).each do |mp|
        should_not have_link("delete", href: micropost_path(mp))
      end
    end

    it { should have_content(@another_user.name) }
    it { should have_content("Foooo") }
  end
```